# iText Generated PDF Viewing in IE7

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-7, itext, web.xml

I am generating a pdf using iText. When I open the pdf through the link it does not open in IE 7 but works fine in Chrome. I also noticed if I remove the / *from web.xml then it opens perfectly fine in IE 7.
 My security-constraint in web.xml is:
   
      Entire Application
      /*

I have to use the  /* because of security concern.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser does not interpret the pdf as an actual pdf. Try to trick it by adding .pdf in the url. It happened to me too back in the days..